WebGL calculated matrix between two triangles
I was using this library to find the transformation matrix between two triangles. In a 2d canvas context it works well for translating the source triangle the other, but I'm trying to translate my app into WebGL using the same transformations and it seems like the same matrices don't quiet work. Here's what I'm trying to do
// Here's the vertex shader
const vertexShaderSrc = `
  attribute vec2 a_position;
  attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
   
  uniform mat3 u_matrix;
   
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
   
  void main() {
    vec3 transformedCoords = u_matrix * vec3(a_position,1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(transformedCoords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    
    v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
  }
`;

// and the fragment shader
const fragmentShaderSrc = `
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord; 
  uniform sampler2D u_texture;
   
  void main() {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
  }
`;

// This is what's in my render loop
let { triangles } = this.state;

let gl = this.context;
let glAttrs = this.glAttrs;
let video = this.videos;

// I'm using video textures, this updates them. Working fine
this.updateTexture(gl, glAttrs.texture, video);


for (var j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++) {
  let pnts = triangles[j];
  
  // triangles are stored in [0, 1] coordinates, 
  // this translates them into [-1, 1] coordinates, 
  let positions = [
    pnts[0][0] * 2 - 1,
    pnts[0][1] * -2 + 1,
    pnts[1][0] * 2 - 1,
    pnts[1][1] * -2 + 1,
    pnts[2][0] * 2 - 1,
    pnts[2][1] * -2 + 1,
  ];

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, glAttrs.positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array(positions),
    gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW,
  );

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    glAttrs.locations.position,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0,
  );
  
  // Use the [0,1] coordinates for the textures, again works fine
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, glAttrs.textureBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
      pnts[0][0],
      pnts[0][1],
      pnts[1][0],
      pnts[1][1],
      pnts[2][0],
      pnts[2][1],
    ]),
    gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW,
  );

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    glAttrs.locations.texture,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0,
  );
  
  // these are the pre-calculated 2D matrix values 
  // from the transformation-matrix library. 
  // The drawing works as expected for the identity matrix
  let { a, b, c, d, e, f } = this.matrices[idx][j];
  let matrix = [a, b, 0, c, d, 0, e, f, 1];

  gl.uniformMatrix3fv(glAttrs.uniforms.matrix, false, matrix);
  gl.uniform1i(glAttrs.uniforms.sampler, 0);
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

I'm pretty new to WebGL so I'm sure there's just some difference I'm not aware of, but I can't figure out what it is.

The way I've got this working is just by manually applying the matrix to the points. I just changed the render loop to
for (var j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++) {
  let pnts = triangles[j];
  let transformed = pnts.map((pnt) => {
    let absolute = [gl.canvas.width * pnt[0], gl.canvas.height * pnt[1]];
    let transformed = this.applyToPoint(this.matrices[j], absolute);
    let relative = [
      transformed[0] / gl.canvas.width,
      transformed[1] / gl.canvas.height,
    ];

    return relative;
  });
  
  // Using the transformed points here
  let positions = [
    transformed[0][0] * 2 - 1,
    transformed[0][1] * -2 + 1,
    transformed[1][0] * 2 - 1,
    transformed[1][1] * -2 + 1,
    transformed[2][0] * 2 - 1,
    transformed[2][1] * -2 + 1,
  ];
  
  // Everything else stays the same, except 
  // the matrix remains the identity 
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, glAttrs.positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array(positions),
    gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW,
  );

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    glAttrs.locations.position,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0,
  );
  
  // transforming these points too keeps the src from distorting
  // but that's not the effect I'm going for
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, glAttrs.textureBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
      pnts[0][0],
      pnts[0][1],
      pnts[1][0],
      pnts[1][1],
      pnts[2][0],
      pnts[2][1],
    ]),
    gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW,
  );

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    glAttrs.locations.texture,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0,
  );
  
  // This can just stay the identity matrix
  let matrix = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1];

  gl.uniformMatrix3fv(glAttrs.uniforms.matrix, false, matrix);
  gl.uniform1i(glAttrs.uniforms.sampler, 0);
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

